# How to turn a recorded Macro into an automated Macro in VBA when data come from another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have recorded the following macro to sort data in the range "B3:U47" based on the values of the column "C3:C47".

```
Sub Sorting_Finance()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("C3:C47"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B3:U47")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Every time I want to sort the data, I press Control+n. In order to get it done automatically when a new value is entered in the column C, I tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
if not (intersect(target, Range("C3:C47")) is nothing) then 
    call Sorting_Finance
end if
end sub
```

But the fact is that the data in the column "C3:C47" come from another sheet, so it doesn't work. Is there anything I can do for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of VBA sorting. The recorded version is the 'longhand' version. You can use the 'shorthand' version and set the primary sort order column while adapting the range to suit current data.

BTW, you should know whether you have a header row or not. xlGuess should be replaced with either xlYes or xlNo I've used xlYes.

In Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sorting_Finance()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance")
        'range B3 to column U down to the last row with data in C
        With .Range(.Cells(3, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 18))
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

In the Finance worksheet code sheet, use the same method to define the Intersect range.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(3, "C"), Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Sorting_Finance
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Since you are changing the values as you re-sort them, disable event handling so one iteration doesn't run on top of another.